# Can I Generate a Password Rest Token in mvc 3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an MVC 3 application, in which I am using actionMailer to send out emails (to the C drive for now) for Password reset etc.
The problem is I can send the e-mail and password reset no problem however there is nothing to stop the user from using that same email over and over again.
So I believe I need to send a token with the e-mail.
I've being trying to use...

```
   var token = WebSecurity.GeneratePasswordResetToken(email);
```

I get following error...

```
  You must call the "WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection" method before you call any other method of the "WebSecurity" class. This call should be placed in an _AppStart.cshtml file in the root of your site.
```

UPDATE: Basically I'm looking for the steps involved in doing the above for an MVC 3 application!
I have no webpages tables in my database and would prefer not to have to add such tables now.

I have searched around the web and keep getting answers related to MVC 4, which as far as I can understand as built-in facility for the above.

I have webMatrix.WebData in place in my references folder, and have set "CopyToLocal = true".

If anyone as any advice can you please be as detailed as possible in your suggestions, also I can post up whatever additional code needed. Please keep in mind this is MVC 3 application.

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory.

Comment: Thanks thats real helpful. Still learning here, so please enlightening me !

Comment: Do you use WebSecurity to create the user accounts as well?

Comment: I believe so, I'm maintaining the previous developer's code , so still getting familiar, one of the actions used for adding users uses MemebershipCreateStatus, with the namespace System.Web.Security, so yes I think !

Comment: I also tried installing SimpleMembershipMvc3, but started getting problems with the connecting string in the App_Start\SimpleMembershipMvc3.cs, errors like "cannot convert system guid to int", not sure I follow whats happening there has I'm using the email parameter for the token ?